# Consulta PHP PDO no funciona editar

Tags: php, ajax

Hola tengo un detalle es que tengo una pagina que me muestra los datos de una tabla de la bd entonces cuando voy a modificar abre un modal y me carga los datos, hasta ahi todo bien el problema viene al darle actualizar me sale el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Database::update() in Ruta:edita.php:24

Aqui dejo mi **conector.php**

```
<?php
    class Database 
    {
        // private static $dbName = 'naw' ; 
        private static $dbName = 'naw'; 
        // private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
        private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
        // private static $dbUsername = 'root';
        private static $dbUsername = 'root';
        // private static $dbUserPassword = '';
        private static $dbUserPassword = '';

        private static $cont  = null;


        public static function connect()
        {
            // One connection through whole application
                if ( null == self::$cont )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        die($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return self::$cont;
        }

        public static function query($query) {
            try {

                $q = self::$cont->prepare($query);
                $q->execute();

                $data = $q->fetchAll();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e;
            }
            return $data;
        }



        public static function disconnect()
        {
            self::$cont = null;
        }
    }
?>
```

Y aqui mi **edita.php**:

```
<?php
    require_once '../php/conector.php';

    $id                = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre      = $_POST['nombre'];
    $telefono      = $_POST['telefono'];
    $correo        = $_POST['correo'];
    $comuna          = $_POST['comuna'];
    $actualizado = $_POST['actualizado'];


    // function update_modal() {
        try {
            $pdo = new Database;
            $pdo->connect();
            $sql = "UPDATE `menmbresia` 
                                                        SET `nombre_apellido` =             $nombre         ,
                                                                `telefono` =                            $telefono       ,
                                                                `correo` =                              $correo         ,
                                                                `comuna` =                              $comuna         ,
                                                                `actualizado` =                     $actualizado,
                                                        WHERE id ='{$id}'";
            try {
                $w = $pdo->update($sql);
            } catch (PDOExecption $e) {
                $pdo->rollback();
            }
        } catch ( PDOExecption $e) {
        }
        // database::disconnect();
        $pdo->disconnect();
        return;
    // }

            ?>
```

Pense en agregarle esto a miconector pero no se si este bien

```
    public static function update($sql) {
        try {

            $q = self::$cont->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
```

Pero con eso no me sale error pero igual no me edita nada, quien sabe que podria hacer? con algun ejemplo oalgo que soy nuevo en php y menos con ajax y php pdo .-.

Comment: Por supuesto que tienes que agregar eso al conector. Yo lo veo bien todo. Funciona tu consulta por si sola en la base de datos? Has verificado que la consulta que estas pasando al conector este bien, con un var_dump o algo asi?

Comment: Otra cosa. Realmente tu problema es que no se actualizan los datos. Te aconsejo que puedas [edit] tu pregunta y hacer enfasis en eso, porque parece que tu problema es que no reconoce el metodo update(), pero tu mismo has respondido que ya solucionaste eso.

Comment: Yo renombraría la propiedad *$cont* a *$con* o *$conn*. A primera vista me parecio que se iba a usar como un contador.

Answer (score 1):

Si añades ese método ya no tendrías el error. Aunque ese método puede ejecutar otro tipo de consultas, como de tipo DELETE. Para limitar esto puedes hacer una validación sencilla de la consulta SQL, por ejemplo:

```
public static function update( $sql ) {

    if ( self::isUpdate( $sql )) {
        $q = self::$cont->prepare( $sql );

        return $q->execute();
    } 

    return FALSE;
}

private static function isUpdate( $sql ) {

    return ( strpos( $sql, "UPDATE " ) == 0 );
}
```

'isUpdate()' solo te va a validar que "UPDATE " aparezca en la primera posición del string con tu sentencia SQL, desde ahí puedes añadir las mejoras que te parezca o crear métodos similares para validar otras sentencias, en una clase independiente con este propósito.

Un saludo.

Comment: Tu respuesta esta bien, lo unico que es muy propensa a injecciones sql porque ejecuta el sql puro. Tienes alguna sugerencia para evitar las injecciones?

Comment: @Einer eso daría  para mucho, puedes usar librerías que analizan el código, o añadir la lógica que requieras. Sólo añadí una base para responder al problema inmediato y una forma muy básica de desarrollar la lógica atendiendo al nombre del método 'update()' y lo que se supone que hace.